# Concatenating data frame values in R not working as expected

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider the following code:

```
> a <- data.frame(name=c('a','b','c'))
> b <- data.frame(type=a$name[1])
> c <- data.frame(type=c(a$name[1],a$name[2]))
> b
  type
1    a
> c
  type
1    1
2    2
```

Why does `b$type` have a value of `a`, the actual assigned value, whereas `c$type` takes the value of the index number (`1` and `2`)?

Answer (score 4):

Well, a$name is a *factor*, not a character vector and You can't concatenate factors like that (because the `c` function currently doesn't handle factors). Factors are really integer vectors with a `levels` attribute (and a class), so the `c` function just uses the integer values. This can probably be considered a bug.

One way to combine factor is by using `unlist`, which has special code for this case:

```
c <- data.frame(type=unlist(list(a$name[1], a$name[2])))
```

Another way is to convert to character vectors:

```
c <- data.frame(type=c(as.character(a$name[1]), as.character(a$name[2])))
```

A third way is to use a character vector from the start:

```
a <- data.frame(name=c('a','b','c'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
c <- data.frame(type=c(a$name[1],a$name[2]))
```